# Open Hyperspectral image AVIRIS file in R

Tags: r

How I can open the Hyperspectral image in R and print a scatter plot for the data. Thank you if you provided me with good information regarding this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the [ripa package?](http://cran.nexr.com/web/packages/ripa/index.html)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.